# Ignore exceptions thrown and caught inside a library

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pycharm

The Python standard library and other libraries I use (e.g. PyQt) sometimes use exceptions for non-error conditions. Look at the following except of the function `os.get_exec_path()`. It uses multiple `try` statements to catch exceptions that are thrown while trying to find some environment data.

```
try:
    path_list = env.get('PATH')
except TypeError:
    path_list = None

if supports_bytes_environ:
    try:
        path_listb = env[b'PATH']
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass
    else:
        if path_list is not None:
            raise ValueError(
                "env cannot contain 'PATH' and b'PATH' keys")
        path_list = path_listb

    if path_list is not None and isinstance(path_list, bytes):
        path_list = fsdecode(path_list)
```

These exceptions do not signify an error and are thrown under normal conditions. When using exception breakpoints for one of these exceptions, the debugger will also break in these library functions.

Is there a way in PyCharm or in Python in general to have the debugger not break on exceptions that are thrown and caught inside a library without any involvement of my code?

Comment: Analogues question regarding Java - [In a Java debugger, how to ignore exceptions never passing through my code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3335587/95735)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet, you can vote for it:

- [add ability to break (add breakpoint) on exceptions only for my files](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6396)

Comment: It seems I already did that :). How do other people work around that problem? I currently don't see any other way than just hitting the continue button every time the debugger breaks on such an exception.

Answer (score 8):

in PyCharm, go to Run-->View Breakpoints, and check "On raise" and **"Ignore library files**".

[image: screenshot of the options menu]

The first option makes the debugger stop whenever an exception is raised, instead of just when the program terminates, and the second option gives PyCharm the policy to ignore library files, thus searching mainly in your code.

The solution was found thanks to [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder)'s [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6396) to the feature request, which has since been added.

Answer (score 1):

For a while I had a complicated scheme which involved something like the following:

```
try( Closeable ignore = Debugger.newBreakSuppression() )
{
   ... library call which may throw ...
} <-- exception looks like it is thrown here
```

This allowed me to never be bothered by exceptions that were thrown and swallowed within library calls.  If an exception was thrown by a library call and was not caught, then it would appear as if it occurred at the closing curly bracket.

The way it worked was as follows:

`Closeable` is an interface which extends `AutoCloseable` without declaring any checked exceptions.

`ignore` is just a name that tells IntelliJ IDEA to not complain about the unused variable, and it is necessary because silly java does not support `try( Debugger.newBreakSuppression() )`.

`Debugger` is my own class with debugging-related helper methods.

`newBreakSuppression()` was a method which would create a thread-local instance of some `BreakSuppression` class which would take note of the fact that we want break-on-exception to be temporarily suspended.

Then I had an exception breakpoint with a break condition that would invoke my `Debugger` class to ask whether it is okay to break, and the `Debugger` class would respond with a "no" if any `BreakSuppression` objects were instantiated.

That was extremely complicated, because the VM throws exceptions before my code has loaded, so the filter could not be evaluated during program startup, and the debugger would pop up a dialog complaining about that instead of ignoring it. (I am not complaining about that, I hate silent errors.) So, I had to have a terrible, horrible, do-not-try-this-at-home hack where the break condition would look like this: `java.lang.System.err.equals( this )`  Normally, this would never return
true, because `System.err` is not equal to a thrown exception, therefore the debugger would never break.  However, when my `Debugger` class would get initialized, it would replace `System.err` with a class of its own,
which provided an implementation for `equals(Object)` and returned `true` if the debugger should break.  So, essentially, I was using `System.err` as an eternal global variable.

Eventually I ditched this whole scheme because it is overly complicated and it performs very bad, because exceptions apparently get thrown very often in the java software ecosystem, so evaluating an expression every time an exception is thrown tremendously slows down everything.

Comment: Up-voting this because it reminds me of the stuff I built in _The Incredible Machine_. Ahhh, good times …

Answer (score 0):

There is another SO answer with a solution:
[Debugging with pycharm, how to step into project, without entering django libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164565/debugging-with-pycharm-how-to-step-into-project-without-entering-django-librar/15186219#15186219)

It is working for me, except I still go into the "_pydev_execfile.py" file, but I haven't stepped into other files after adding them to the exclusion in the linked answer.

Comment: Isn't that other question about the _Step into_ function rather than exception breakpoints? Or are the two related in a way that solves my problem?