# How do I prevent the Intellij python debugger from stepping into builtin functions?

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ professional using the python plugin and when debugging I often find myself stepping into the python library code itself when trying to "step into" a method. For instance:

```
myfunc(random.randint(0,15))
```

results in me being in the builtin function for randint if I try and step into myfunc.

Is this configurable somewhere? I am using IntelliJ 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now (June 2013), this feature is not supported in PyCharm.

Here is a ticket for adding the feature: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9101

If you are reading this after June 2013, then check the ticket to see if it is still in State "Open".

If the ticket is still open then please vote for it!

A workaround can be found here: [Debugging with pycharm, how to step into project, without entering django libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164565/debugging-with-pycharm-how-to-step-into-project-without-entering-django-librar)

Comment: I tried this adding random, Random, randint, etc to it and it always seems to step in.

Comment: I edited the main answer. Please refer back to that now. Short answer: not supported currently (June 2013)